# Is there an algorithm for optimization of expressions?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, expression

For example I have the array of tokens for expression **x+2*(4*7)**:

```
{ "x" , "+" , "2" , "*" , "(" , "4" , "*" , "7" , ")" }
```

I need get output like **x+56**. This is a simple example that can be much more difficult. I know about Dijkstra's shunting yard algorithm, but not sure if this can to help specifically for optimization. Frankly, I do not know how to understand that expression maximum optimized because I can not see all the possible methods of optimization. Perhaps there is an algorithm that takes into account all nuances?

Comment: How difficult? Some expressions that don't involve just constants can nevertheless be optimized to a constant, for example `popcnt(x) + popcnt(~x)` is always however many bits `x` is wide and `sin(x)^2 + cos(x)^2` is 1 (in idealized math anyway), but constant folding would not find either of those things.

Answer (score 3):

In the case from your question, the technique used to optimize the expression is called [constant folding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding). It finds expressions where every value is a constant and replaces that expression with the result of the operation.

```
Start with x+2*(4*7)
Notice 4*7 is an operation with constant arguments
Compute 4*7=28, replace in expression to get x+2*(28)
Notice (28) can be de-bracketed, to get x+2*28
Notice 2*28 is an operation with constant arguments
Compute 2*28=56, replace in expression to get x+56
Notice there are no more operations with all constant arguments
End with x+56
```

See also:

- [Optimizing compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler_optimization) (other optimization techniques)
- [Context free grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) (starting down the path of transforming text into a tree structure that's easier to work with).

Answer (score 1):

What you're probably looking for is a [computer algebra system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system).  There are [several open source systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_computer_algebra_systems) available; you can also use the [Wolfram Alpha API](http://products.wolframalpha.com/api/) for free if you limit your use to a few thousand api calls per month.